# How do I set a category attribute for NUnit C++/CLI tests?

Tags: unit-testing, c++-cli, nunit, categories

I'm trying to set a category so I can exclude hardware tests on our build server:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    using namespace NUnit::Framework;

    [TestFixture]
    [Category("RequiresHardware")]
    public ref class UnitTest_SomeHardwareTests
    {
        ...
    };
}
```

...but I get an error when I try and use categories:

```
1>c:\projects\testing\UnitTest_MainSystem.h(14) : error C2872: 'CategoryAttribute' : ambiguous symbol
1>        could be 'c:\program files (x86)\nunit 2.5.9\bin\net-2.0\framework\nunit.framework.dll : NUnit::Framework::CategoryAttribute'
1>        or       'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\system.dll : System::ComponentModel::CategoryAttribute'
```

How do I tell it to use NUnit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following two approaches work for me:

Either, explicitly indicate the fully qualified attribute name in the attribute specification, i.e.

```
[NUnit::Framework::Category("RequiresHardware")]
```

Or, add a `using` declaration to indicate exactly which `CategoryAttribute` you intend to use:

```
using NUnit::Framework::CategoryAttribute;
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try that. Thanks!